# Watir Webdriver Detection

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

Is there a way to detect whether someone is conducting web testing using watir-webdriver on your site? I have read somewhere that it is fairly easy to detect watir/selenium, but I never managed to get more details about it.

I have tried UserAgent detection, but that's not something very useful as far as it's easy to change it.

Comment: I doubt if it's possible. The idea of Selenium is to simulate real user actions. You can't possibly detect it from server side, unless Selenium fails to simulate (e.g. click really fast). User Agent approach won't work if someone runs it using common browsers with default UA.

Comment: I also assumed that. Please enter your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @user1177636 - As it seems, we do not have new answers. I did not answer the question, you did it, so please make the answer and I will mark as correct. Once again appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I will make my comments into an answer as requested.

I doubt if it's possible. The idea of Selenium is to automate browsers by simulating actions like real users. You can't possibly detect it from server side, unless Selenium fails to simulate (e.g. click really fast, but if the Selenium code is written deliberately to simulate a real user in a slow fashion, then I'd say it will be difficult to detect).

On the other hand, User Agent approach won't work if someone runs it using common browsers with default UA.